# Is sphericity violated if my sample size is less than the repeated measurement count?

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures, assumptions, sphericity

In SPSS, I find that the Mauchley's test does not provide any result if the sample size is less than the repeated measurement count.

I have a sample size of 19 and a repeated measures of 22. My Mauchley test's value results are as 'p=.' (just a dot) and chi square values = '.' (just a dot; no number gets displayed).

I observed that:

(1) If my repeated measurement is greater than sample size (eg. Repeated measurement = 22 and sample size  = 19), the Mauchley's test fails to give a value for chi-squared and p-value, and displays only a '".". However, I could see a value for Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt.

(2) if I include only 5 repeated measurement in my analysis for sample size = 19 (i.e repeated measurements < sample size),  Mauchley's test gives a value for chi square,p-value and other correction values.

In my first case, should I assume that the sphericity has been violated and go for a correction?